# Setting Environmental Variables for Python on a Mac - seems not to work?

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables

This Drives me nuts...

I use the latest EPD Distribution on the latest Mac and I want to study the book "Python for software design". Therein, Chap. 4, is one should load to play around with.

But to do that I seemingly need to set a PATH variable to the relevant directory. As I am not very familiar I looked around and finally added this to my .bash-profile:

```
"PYTHONPATH="$HOME/Dropbox/Programming/swampy-2.0"
```

The check with the Terminal:

```
Andreass-Mac-mini:~ ak$ $PYTHONPATH
-bash: /Users/ak/Dropbox/Programming/swampy-2.0: is a directory
```

Up to this point I would say it should work. And then comes this:

```
>>> from TurtleWorld import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from TurtleWorld import *
ImportError: No module named TurtleWorld
```

It is the right file name, the correct directory and it seems to me that the path is not right?

So what do I have to do/change that it works on my Mac?

Edit: and by the way - (on a different) I also created a directory .MacOSX and put the file environment.plist therein with the same path variable. Nothing changed :-(

Thanks
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Use the `export` command in your .bash-profile to make environment variables appear in other contexts:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/Dropbox/Programming/swampy-2.0
```

Comment: @A.K. To confirm, can you see TurtleWorld.py in `ls $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @A.K. Hmm, if you manually manipulate `sys.path` within Python, can you import TurtleWorld?

Comment: Yep. That works. So the question remains how do I get it into that list?

Comment: @A.K. Are you running your .bash-profile like a command, or are you `source`-ing it? I'm just stumped as to why an exported `PYTHONPATH` wouldn't affect the `sys.path`.

Comment: Sorry. But here you got me. I do not have a clue what you with that. I just changed the file .bash_profile.

Comment: @A.K. After you made the changes to your file to include the `export` command, did you load the file via `source .bash_profile`?

Comment: No. I did not. I'll. Thanks!!

Comment: No, it didn't work. I put in the lines: PYTHONPATH="$HOME/Dropbox/Programming/swampy-2.0"
export PYTHONPATH

I did source .bash_profile

And then I checket sys.path ... and it wasn't in there .-((  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you name your script Turtleworld.py? If so, that is the issue. The module can't be imported if your script name is the same as the module name. Hope this helps! :D